# gem 'country_select', github: 'stefanpenner/country_select' is not working with rails 4

Tags: html, ruby-on-rails, rubygems, rails-4-2-1

I am using `gem 'country_select', github: 'stefanpenner/country_select'` in my gem file and in my form i have defined it like this:

```
<%= form_for(@account_detail) do |f| %>

  <div class="field">
    <%= f.label :city %><br>
    <%= f.text_field :city %>
  </div>
  <div class="field">
    <%= f.label :zip %><br>
    <%= f.number_field :zip %>
  </div>
  <div class="field">
    <%= f.label :first_name %><br>
    <%= f.text_field :first_name %>
  </div>
  <div class="field">
    <%= f.label :last_name %><br>
    <%= f.text_field :last_name %>
  </div>
  <div class="field">
    <%= f.label :country %><br>
    <%= f.country_select("account_detail", "country") %>
  </div>
  <div class="actions">
    <%= f.submit %>
  </div>
<% end %>
```

on submit its giving error `ActionView::Template::Error (wrong number of arguments (4 for 0)):`

Which gem is best to show all countries?

Comment: I think the country_select gem version issues with your rails, check that version.

Comment: I had tried it with all its versions its not working

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would use:

```
<%= f.country_select :country %>
```

If you like to prioritize some countries in the select pass them in in an array:

```
 <%= f.country_select :country, {priority_countries: %w(<COUNTRY CODE i.e. US>), prompt: 'Select Country'} %>
```

You can add `class: 'your-class'` and `id` or whatever just as with any other field if you like. Hope it helps.

Comment: what version of the gem are you using? Try locking to `gem 'country_select', '~> 2.1.0'` or `2.2.0` Anyway, it works for me in rails 4.1.8/ruby 2.1.2

Comment: me having rails version4.1.0 and ruby 2.1.5p273  and gem 'country_select', '~> 2.1.0' still not working tried with 2.2.0 also but no improvement

Comment: Works when I change `gem 'country_selected'` for `gem 'country_select', '~> 2.1.0'`. Thank you, @Thomas.

Answer (score 1):

This should do!

```
<%= f.country_select :country, { priority_countries: ["GB", "US"], selected: "GB" } %>
```

Comment: I used exactly same ut o luck 
NoMethodError - undefined method `-' for #<Hash:0x00007f42afe2fdf8>

Answer (score 0):

I have solved this issue by adding this method in my model:

```
def country_name
    country = ISO3166::Country[country_code]
    country.translations[I18n.locale.to_s] || country.name
  end
```

and in view change given line :

```
<%= f.country_select("account_detail", "country") %>
```

to this:

```
<%= f.country_select :country, format: :with_alpha2 %>
```

Hope this will help to someone else who will face this problem.